# Аналог DataGrid в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть простое веб приложение в котором нужно вывести несколько таблиц. Есть ли в `ASP.NET` или `ASP.NET MVC 5` аналоги `DataGrid` из `WPF` или `DataGridView` из форм ? Как удобнее и правильней вывести таблицу ?

Comment: может помочь  `WebGrid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ASP.NET MVC` не имеет встроенных элементов управления привязкой данных,таких как `GridView,DetailsView`.`WebGrid` предоставляет аналогичные функции, такие как **привязки данных,сортировка,подкачка,упорядочение,форматирование столбцов**.В основном `WebGrid` используется для отображения данных на веб-странице с использованием элементов таблицы `HTML`. Он отображает данные в табличном формате, а также поддерживает настраиваемое форматирование столбцов, пейджинга, сортировки и асинхронных обновлений через `AJAX`.
Вот вам полная [статья](http://www.techstrikers.com/Articles/webgrid-in-mvc5-with-razor-view-and-entity-framework6.php)